# GA-B250M-DS3H won't boot with all 4 RAM slots occupied

Tags: memory, bios, motherboard

I have a PC with a Gigabyte GA-B250M-DS3H motherboard which since I built it has been using 2 8GB DIMMs and worked fine.

I decided to add another two DIMMs, but when I do this the computer won't boot, it simply keeps attempting to boot and then restarting, without any output on the screen.

The four DIMMs are all the same type (Crucial CT8G4DFS824A) and this morning I tried each individually and all worked fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a pic of one of the BIOS memory screens. The machine only had one DIMM installed when this was taken.

I couldn't see any obvious LEDs indicating an error code.

[image]

Here's a screenshot from the Crucial scanner in its functioning state:

[image]

Comment: A few things to try. When system boots with just one stick. Shut it down. Disconnect the mains power and then Reset the Firmware settings by shorting the CLR_CMOS (or similar) header on motherboard for about 10 – 15 seconds. Power on, load optimum defaults and check again. Also clean the RAM slots with IPA cleaner and make sure that all 4 DIMMs are fully inserted and locked in the respective slots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reseating the CPU. I guess that some of the CPU pins were off and not making a good contact, taking it out/apart has solved.

BTW I did this fix months ago, a few weeks after posting this, and it's been going strong ever since.